# Find Lipshitz constant

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $x, y$ be two vectors in $R^n$. Let $\pi$ be permutation on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with uniform distribution.

Find Lipshitz constaants of the following functions:
$$
f(\pi)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_{\pi(i)}y_i
$$
and
$$
g(\pi)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_{\pi(i)}y_{\pi(i)}.
$$

Thank you.

My work so far:

I've tried function $f$ (for $g$ I am confused);
$$
|f(\sigma)-f(\pi)|\leq \left|\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_{\sigma(i)}-y_ix_{\pi(i)}\right|
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i||x_{\sigma(i)}-x_{\pi(i)}|\leq 2\|x\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{1}d_{n}(\sigma, \pi).
$$

Can one do better?

Comment: Can you post your work so far?

Comment: I think for $g$ function we have infinity norm of $y$ instead of $l_1$-norm$$
|g(\sigma)-g(\pi)|\leq \left|\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_{\sigma(i)}-y_ix_{\pi(i)}\right|
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i||x_{\sigma(i)}-x_{\pi(i)}|\leq 2\|x\|_{\infty} \|y\|_{\infty}d_{n}(\sigma, \pi).
$$